# Deprecated Warning

Tags: updating, function

Just received this deprecated warning in the dashboard. However the file it refers to does not contain the deprecated code. Any ideas? I can locate the deprecated function in several core files though. I have the latest upgrade so not sure why it is returning this error? Anyone come across this as well?

Calling getChildren() to fetch an element’s target relations has been deprecated.

**Full stack Trace:**

29  Deprecation error: Calling getChildren() to fetch an element’s target relations has been deprecated. Use the [relatedTo](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) param instead. 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/models/BaseElementModel.php (545)

28  Craft\UserModel::getChildren()
27  call_user_func_array(array(Craft\UserModel, "getChildren"), array()) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php (478)

26  __TwigTemplate_c931853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484::getAttribute(Craft\UserModel, "getChildren", array(), "method") 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php (41)

25  Template: user/profile (13) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/c9/31/853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484.php (43)

24  __TwigTemplate_c931853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484::block_main(array("craft" => Craft\CraftVariable, "blx" => Craft\CraftVariable, "now" => Craft\DateTime, "loginUrl" => "http://domainname/login"), array("extraHead" => array(__TwigTemplate_9b802816e813e2db8b5808c859ea97942fccd5b7f9bec86451c103eb6b2e5f27, "block_extraHead"), "main" => array(__TwigTemplate_c931853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484, "block_main"))) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php (144)

23  Template: user/_layout (101)
Called from /serverpath/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/9b/80/2816e813e2db8b5808c859ea97942fccd5b7f9bec86451c103eb6b2e5f27.php (227)

22  __TwigTemplate_9b802816e813e2db8b5808c859ea97942fccd5b7f9bec86451c103eb6b2e5f27::doDisplay(array("craft" => Craft\CraftVariable, "blx" => Craft\CraftVariable, "now" => Craft\DateTime, "loginUrl" => "http://domainname/login"), array("extraHead" => array(__TwigTemplate_9b802816e813e2db8b5808c859ea97942fccd5b7f9bec86451c103eb6b2e5f27, "block_extraHead"), "main" => array(__TwigTemplate_c931853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484, "block_main"))) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php (279)

21  __TwigTemplate_9b802816e813e2db8b5808c859ea97942fccd5b7f9bec86451c103eb6b2e5f27::displayWithErrorHandling(array("craft" => Craft\CraftVariable, "blx" => Craft\CraftVariable, "now" => Craft\DateTime, "loginUrl" => "http://domainname/login"), array("extraHead" => array(__TwigTemplate_9b802816e813e2db8b5808c859ea97942fccd5b7f9bec86451c103eb6b2e5f27, "block_extraHead"), "main" => array(__TwigTemplate_c931853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484, "block_main"))) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php (253)

20  Template: user/_layout (1)
Called from /serverpath/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/c9/31/853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484.php (31)

19  __TwigTemplate_c931853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484::doDisplay(array("craft" => Craft\CraftVariable, "blx" => Craft\CraftVariable, "now" => Craft\DateTime, "loginUrl" => "http://domainname/login"), array("main" => array(__TwigTemplate_c931853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484, "block_main"))) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php (279)

18  __TwigTemplate_c931853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484::displayWithErrorHandling(array("craft" => Craft\CraftVariable, "blx" => Craft\CraftVariable, "now" => Craft\DateTime, "loginUrl" => "http://domainname/login"), array("main" => array(__TwigTemplate_c931853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484, "block_main"))) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php (253)

17  __TwigTemplate_c931853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484::display(array()) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php (264)

16  __TwigTemplate_c931853f702811dd00a8d276cbef73ef24b391da71bd1ae0c434f5db4f701484::render(array()) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php (292)

15  Twig_Environment::render("user/profile", array()) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php (220)

14  Craft\TemplatesService::render("user/profile", array()) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/controllers/BaseController.php (74)

13  Craft\TemplatesController::renderTemplate("user/profile", array()) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php (55)

12  Craft\TemplatesController::actionRender("user/profile", array())

11  ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs(Craft\TemplatesController, array("user/profile", array())) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CAction.php (108)

10  CInlineAction::runWithParamsInternal(Craft\TemplatesController, ReflectionMethod, array("p" => "user/profile", "variables" => array(), "template" => "user/profile")) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php (47)

9   CInlineAction::runWithParams(array("p" => "user/profile", "variables" => array(), "template" => "user/profile")) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php (308)

8   Craft\TemplatesController::runAction(CInlineAction) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php (286)

7   Craft\TemplatesController::runActionWithFilters(CInlineAction, array()) 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php (265)

6   Craft\TemplatesController::run("render") 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php (282)

5   Craft\WebApp::runController("templates/render") 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php (141)

4   Craft\WebApp::processRequest() 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (266)

3   Craft\WebApp::processRequest() 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php (180)

2   Craft\WebApp::run() 
Called from /serverpath/craft/app/index.php (62)

1   require_once("/serverpath/craft/app/index.php") 
Called from /serverpath/public/index.php (19)

Comment: Hi @Lettie, can you please paste in the entire warning message?

Comment: Try 1) emptying your /craft/storage folder, and/or 2) re-download Craft and replace the /app folder with a fresh copy

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing the actual error message and stack trace, but there is a button next to the deprecation message that you can click that will show the full stack trace to see where the message originated from.

Most like it's coming from a template, but you can update your original message with the stack trace so we can be sure.